# Mixing IObservable and Async<'a> in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable` provided by a library, which listens to events from an external service:

```
let startObservable () : IObservable<'a> = failwith "Given"
```

For each received event I want to execute an action which returns `Async`:

```
let action (item: 'a) : Async<unit> = failwith "Given"
```

I'm trying to implement a processor in lines of

```
let processor () : Async<unit> =
    startObservable()
    |> Observable.mapAsync action
    |> Async.AwaitObservable
```

I've made up `mapAsync` and `AwaitObservable`: ideally they would be provided by some library, which I'm failing to find so far.

Extra requirements:

- Actions should be executed sequentially, so subsequent events get buffered while a previous event is handled.
- If an action throws an error, I want my processor to complete. Otherwise, it never completes.
- Cancellation token passed via `Async.Start` should be respected.

Any hints about the library that I should be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to convert a push-based model (`IObservable<>`) into pull-based (`Async<>`), you'll need to queue to buffer data coming from observable. If queue is size-limited - which tbh. should be to to make entire pipeline safe to not overflood the memory - then also a strategy for buffer overflow is needed.

1. One way is to implement a `MailboxProcessor<>` and custom observable, which would Post data to it. Since MP is a native F# actor implementation, it's able to make ordered processing with queue for buffering spikes.
2. Another option is to use `FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq` (and specifically [AsyncSeq.ofObservableBuffered](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/blob/02cfec8acda46617b593474a847f55cf6523aff2/src/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/AsyncSeq.fs#L998) function) which will turn observable into pull-based async enumerable - underneath it uses mailbox processor from 1st point:

   ```
   startObservable()
   |> AsyncSeq.ofObservableBuffered
   |> AsyncSeq.iterAsync action
   ```

Comment: Is `Async` really pull based? IIRC it's built on callback which seems like push to me.

Comment: I would use the `AsyncSeq` option, personally.

Comment: @Justanothermetaprogrammer callbacks doesn't have to imply push-based model, especially since we have lazy evaluation here. `Async` execution model, just like .NET `Task`, is a variation of iterator pattern: while you compose multiple async calls by callback bindings, the execution itself won't start until you actually *pull* it via `Async.Start`.

Answer (score 1):

Hopac could easily interop with `IObservables`
You could convert Hopac `Jobs` to `Async` with `Job.toAsync`

```
open System
open Hopac

let startObservable () : IObservable<'a> = failwith "Given"

let action (item: 'a) : Job<unit> = failwith "Given"

let processor () : Job<unit> =
    startObservable()
    |> Stream.ofObservable
    |> Stream.mapJob action
    |> Stream.iter
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of using Hopac in my scenario given that I don't need parallel or concurrent processing (except buffering observed events)?

Comment: @Mikhail Hopac has great [Stream library](https://hopac.github.io/Hopac/Hopac.html#def:module%20Hopac.Stream). You could skip all Hopac stuff (alts, promises, operator overload and just focus on Stream part) to make something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/4TeKmVA). Streams allow you to create very memory efficient pipelines which is good for your Azure Functions. Link I provided actually is working code from my Azure Function

Comment: Thanks! Would love to learn more about that Function! Probably off-topic here, could you get in touch e.g. on twitter or F# slack?

Comment: @Mikhail pinged you in Telegram